# How to achieve ombré (or shading) effects?

Tags: color

Is it possible to color a 3D printed object during 3D printing? I am trying to achieve an [*ombré*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ombr%C3%A9) of many colors.

I tried to stop the 3D printing at individual stages and it looks like blocks. Is there a way to achieve a near perfect ombré or is it not possible yet?

The thing I am printing is [Spiral Christmas Balls](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:5129377).

I am trying to achieve something like this effect:

[image: Color gradient or shading effect]

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5EC_qRTojE&ab_channel=CNCKitchen) is what you need?

Comment: No I am trying to achieve something like [this](https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp4064207.jpg).

Comment: make a custom filament or a custom extruder that can accept and mix multiple filament.  may need to be something of a mixer before final extrusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to shade 3D printed objects is dependent on the printer, the plastic in use, and available dye.

Several vendors offer filament with a gradient or rainbow-colored patterns, so that printed objects will vary in color over their volume.

Several 3D printers give the option of changing plastics during printing which would allow this.

A few 3D printers allow injecting dye into the plastic during the printing process, allowing full 3d coloring of the final part.

If you can find a natural colored filament and a dye that will dissolve in the filament, it is possible to color the surface of the filament before it goes into the printer, and there is some mixing in the nozzle.  (This works well with natural-colored ABS and Sharpie markers, but I haven't found a combination that works well with PLA.)

Comment: Do you have any recommendations of a filament?

Comment: This site is not for product endorsements, sorry.

Comment: Ok I was just wondering if there was a good brand or like type. But No problem :)